# Facebook basic user information

Tags: android, facebook

I would like to display some information about the user before using SSO. Something like:

**"Login with facebook as John Smith"**

Is this possible before actually logging in? Like grabbing info from the facebook app?

It'd be nice to express to the user that pressing the button means logging in with the user defined in the fbook app. I just don't want my users thinking they'll get to input an email address and accidentally link their account to their friend's facebook.

Comment: Well that's disappointing. It'd be nice to express to the user that pressing the button means logging in with the user defined in the fbook app. I just don't want my users thinking they'll get to input an email address and accidentally link their account to their friend's facebook.

Comment: Usually on mobile devices, you have a button with title **"Login with facebook"** (*no name included*) because facebook android sdk *cannot* tell you which user is logged in. So you can only have the "Login with facebook" text in the button.

Comment: Yea I know, but I still want to avoid the confusion of people accidentally linking the wrong account. "Login with facebook" suggests you can enter an email and password, rather than suggesting you're going to log in with the facebook app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for why this is **not** possible is that if it would be possible you could easily track who exactly is using your app, without having the permission to collect that user information.

Comment: True but honestly I don't see any harm with a first name and last initial..."Login as John S" I think the Facebook app should provide a current user string with just that First Name and last initial.

Comment: Well it's a privacy thing. An app **could** list publicly all the people who interacted with it with their names. You might not want to see your boss or your wife that you interacted with an app which deals with pornography for instance.

Comment: Yes but without a location and only a first name and last initial that's very easy to deny. Either way i think it's kinda lame lol